# Why is Aut($H$)=$1$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $H\cong Z_2$. I'm trying to understand why Aut($H$)=$1$. This example is from Dummit and Foote. The book says this is implied by $H$ having unique elements of orders $1$ and $2$ and the following corollary:

"If $K$ is any subgroup of the group $G$ and $g\in G$, then $K\cong gKg^{-1}$. Conjugate elements and conjugate subgroups have the same order."

However, I am having trouble seeing why this implies Aut($H$)=$1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity is the only self-isomorphism on a group of order two. Just think about it:  the identity has to go to the identity, so where does the other element go?

Comment: That makes sense. I was confused why they referred to that corollary.